# A phrase or a word for not practising what you are preaching

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Can you please tell me the word, term or phrase for not practising what you are preaching.

Also, if possible, the word, term or phrase for someone who does so.

I am not looking for *hypocrisy* or *hypocrite* but something more specific.

Comment: Hypocrisy and hypocrite *are* exactly what you're looking for. I don't imagine how it could get any more specific...

Comment: I'm not sure how you could get more specific than "hypocrite", seeing as the example you gave is the definition of hypocrisy: "Hypocrite: 1. a person who pretends to have virtues, moral or religious beliefs, principles, etc., that he or she does not actually possess, especially a person whose actions belie stated beliefs." -Dictionary.com Do you perhaps want a more *colloquial* term?

Comment: Under some circumstances a **false flag operative** fits, but hypocrisy is hard to beat here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag

Comment: Please explain exactly why hypocrisy / hypocrite are unsuitable for your purpose, since (as other commenters have noted) their definitions appear to fit your criteria perfectly. As for identifying those who do not practise what they preach, I would imagine that every person who has had the ability to speak has been guilty of this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it rules out the most appropriate answer.

Comment: @Erik Many would say there was one exception.

Comment: sorry to gang up, but *"hypocrisy"* is precisely synonymous with *"a word for not practicing what you are preaching."*  in the New Testament, it might also be "Scribes" or "Pharisees" or "Teachers of the Law", but that isn't because they are inherently synonymous (which they aren't).

Comment: You are misusing  the phrase *more specific* in your question, I'd strongly suggest that you reword this last sentence if you don't want your question closed as being "unclear" or "off-topic". Please, edit your post!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really believe in practicing what you preach, but periodically or for an extended period of time you openly fail to practice it anyway, then I suppose that your conduct can be distinguished from ***hypocrisy***, which *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) defines as

> a feigning to be what one is not or to believe what one does not; *esp.* : the false assumption of an appearance of virtue or religion

Instead, you might refer to your conduct as ***straying***, in the sense of the Eleventh Collegiate's definitions (f) and (g) of the verb *stray*:

> **f :** to wander accidentally from a fixed or chosen rout **g :** ERR, SIN

or ***lapsing***, in the sense of the Eleventh Collegiate's definition 1(a) of the verb *lapse*:

> to fall from an attained and usu. high level (as of morals or manners) to one much lower; *also* : to depart from an accepted pattern or standard.

You might even refer to yourself (for Biblical resonance) as "a ***prodigal*** not yet returned."

For these alternative terms to describe your situation more accurately than *hypocrisy* does, however, your conduct and your intentions must satisfy several crucial conditions: (1) an absence of feigning or false appearance, (2) a genuine belief in the rightness of the practice you have preached, and (3) a longing to return to proper practice that is strong enough to draw you back from your straying, lapse, or prodigality. And even if you do pass muster on those three criteria, if you continue to preach what you have ceased to practice during your period of erring conduct, without acknowledging and condemning the gap between your theory and your practice, the term *hypocrisy* still seems highly applicable to your situation.

---

At the level of everyday office procedures (for example), it might seem too harsh to characterize a boss who makes everyone else submit [TPS reports with cover sheets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fy3rjQGc6lA) but declines to follow that policy him- or herself as being *hypocritical*. But it certainly isn't too harsh to say that such a boss has a ***double standard***. Again, from the Eleventh Collegiate:

> **double standard 2 :** a set of principles that applies differently and usu. more rigorously to one group of people or circumstances than to another ...

Comment: _________Nice Research___________-

Answer (score 4):

Consider the phrase or saying:

*"Do as I say, not as I do."*

Answer (score 2):

I think [sanctimony](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sanctimony) ( sanctimonious)  can fit the context you are describing:

> - feigned piety or righteousness; hypocritical devoutness or high-mindedness.

Or as a more general term:

[Janus -faced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Janus-faced):

> - marked by deliberate deceptiveness especially by pretending one set of feelings and acting under the influence of another.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: Someone who is nor practicing what they are preaching may or may not be sanctimonious about it.  Sanctimonious does not mean "not practicing what you are preaching".

Answer (score 2):

Some idiomatic expressions close to your Question:

> He's not walking the talk.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/walk_the_walk and http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/walk_the_talk

> Big words, small works.

And in Shakespeare's Richard III:

> Fear not, my lord, we will not stand to prate; Talkers are no good
>   doers: be assured We come to use our hands and not our tongues.

Comment: Those are close, but not quite on the mark. The expressions you cite relate more to someone who *fails to live up to their promises* than to someone whose actions contradict their words.

Answer (score 1):

**CYNICAL**

CYNICAL   [(the OED)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cynical) adj. Concerned only with one’s own interests and typically disregarding accepted standards in order to achieve them:  "Some people regard the governor's visit to the hospital as a cynical attempt to win votes."  "A cynical manipulation of public opinion."

**INCOHERENCE and INCOHERENT**

"Coherence can be measured by the shortest distance between what you say and what you do."

> > *Incoherence* -  "The quality of being incoherent." http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incoherence
>
> - *Coherent* – logically connected; consistent.
>     "The same rambling, incoherent manner." http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incoherent)
> - *Incoherent* - Lacking coherence.
>     http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coherent

Other choices might be "inconsistency" and "inconsistent".
Inconsistent or incoherent behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The adjectives, [**double-faced**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-faced) and [**two-faced**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/two-faced), the latter being more common, are often used as synonyms for *hypocrite*. They refer to a person who has *two-faces*, and suggests that the person is deceitful as well as being insincere.

I am interpreting the following OP's request

> Also, if possible, the word, term or phrase for someone who does so.

meaning a person who *does* "practice what they preach", but it is worded ambiguously and it appears I am the only user (up to now) who has identified two separate requests.

The opposite of a *two-faced* person might be ***a person of principles***, a person who has a strong moral code and remains loyal to their ideals, a person whose actions do not contradict their words.

> **Principled**   (of a person or their behavior) acting in accordance with morality and showing recognition of right and wrong. (OED) *moral*,
>   *ethical*, *virtuous*, *righteous*, *upright*, *upstanding*, *high-minded*, *honorable*,
>   *honest*, *incorruptible*

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing or hearing the term “double-faced” applied to people rather than fabric or boards (aside from here), but of course “two-faced” is quite common and I think has the meaning you mean to assign to  “double-faced”.

Answer (score 1):

A phrase I've heard in this context is:

> He talked the talk, but he didn't walk the walk