# An alternative to Hypocrisy to describe dissonance in an individual's reactions

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that can be used to accurately describe a person whose reaction to\or opinions of two different situations is the opposite of what you might expect, and out of all proportion to what the situation warrants.

A person who supports extreme measures to combat something petty, and petty measure in response to something extreme.

For example, believing that you should legally be allowed to shoot someone who steals packages off of your stoop, but think the penalty for killing someone while DUI should be community service.

I'm looking for a word other than "hypocrisy" because the individual holds everyone to the same standards, but it is these standards that are skewed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A phrase or a word for not practising what you are preaching](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199456/a-phrase-or-a-word-for-not-practising-what-you-are-preaching)

Comment: If it does answer the question then this question should be closed too as, apparently, the linked answer led only to opinion.

Comment: No, because that question covers someone who holds other people to different standards from them self, not someone who holds widely different views on similar things.

Comment: From your description, I am tempted to say the word is 'human'.  I mean that many of us do not stop to think how often our pet loathings relate to (mis)behaviour of which we ourselves are guilty.  It is an interesting human paradox.  The same person can be irascible and hypocritical.  That does not mean that there can be a single word like 'hypocritoirascibility' as if the condition were a single thing, any more than, say, being red and square could be a single quality, say, 'erythrotetragonal' (or, rather, 'erythrotrtragonality'.

Comment: @Tuffy, I'm looking for a language related answer rather than a social one. Some kind of discription.

Comment: @Aaargh Zombies I understand that.  My answer is language-related.  To the best of my knowledge, there is no such word as that which you seek.  Of course, I may be proved wrong by someone's providing such a word, evidenced by a dictionary definition.  short of this, no one can prove the nonexistence  of a word.  But I can give you a reason why the word you seek probably does not exist, which is that the demand for such a word has not arisen or not in sufficient frequency for a word to 'catch on'.  That is, after all, how new words arise.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a word, it could be a phrases.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Comment: @tchrist, Compliments don't need to be precise, criticisms do.

Answer (score 1):

The person is **inconsistent / irrational**.  The behavior or attitude is **disproportionate / out of proportion**.  Overall we might say that the person has **not thought things through carefully**.  At any rate you can play with these ideas with a thesaurus to find something that fits your context.

Answer (score 0):

Perverse, Merriam Webster, Meaning 2: obstinate in what is right, reasonable or expected.

Perverse: meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary

> adjective us / pərˈvɜrs /
> having the effect of being, or intended to be, the opposite of what is usually expected or considered reasonable

Comment: The previous edit was a perverse edit.